Using async task to throw an exception after some time
I'm trying to create a forced timeout mechanism that runs asynchronously.
Ideally I need to run a task, without waiting for it, and I expect that after some time it throws an exception to mimic a timeout.
My problem is that I can't change how the methods are called in the main thread and just can add methods there.
I also know that exceptions that are thrown in async Tasks that are not awaited are never caught in the Main Thread. But that's exactly what I need and can't find a solution.
To exemplify my problem here is a sample code (The real code runs in an IIS server as a result of a REST call):
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        //Main method which I don't have control over, to change how other methods are called, I can only add methods here.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            try
            {
                //Forced timeout
                Console.Write("Init timeout \n");
                var forcedTimeout = myForcedTimeoutMethod(1000);

                Console.Write("Init something \n");
                //Do something that might be long
                //Just pretending the main thread is still doing some work that should take longer than 1 second
                AsyncUtil.RunSync<bool>(() => ForcedTimeoutContext.Wait(2000));


                Console.Write("Method finished \n");
                forcedTimeout.Dispose();


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write("Exception caught: " + e.Message);
            }
        }

        public static ForcedTimeoutContext myForcedTimeoutMethod(int TimeInMs)
        {

            ForcedTimeoutContext forcedTimeout = new ForcedTimeoutContext();
            forcedTimeout.TokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            forcedTimeout.Task = Task.Run(async delegate
            {

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(TimeInMs), forcedTimeout.TokenSource.Token);
                forcedTimeout.TokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                throw new Exception("Forced timeout reached");
            });

            return forcedTimeout;
        }
    }

    //Context class to be able to Dispose and cancel the timeout if needed
    class ForcedTimeoutContext : IDisposable
    {
        public CancellationTokenSource TokenSource;
        public Task Task;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (TokenSource != null)
                TokenSource.Dispose();
            if (Task != null)
                Task.Dispose();
        }

        public static async Task<bool> Wait(int ssms)
        {
            await Task.Delay(ssms);
            return true;
        }

        public static void TimeoutException(Task task, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
        {
            if (tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                task.Dispose();
                tokenSource.Dispose();
                throw new Exception("Forced timeout");
            }
        }
    }

    //Utility helper to run async methods synchronously
    public class AsyncUtil
    {
        private static readonly TaskFactory taskFactory = new TaskFactory(
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskCreationOptions.None,
            TaskContinuationOptions.None,
            TaskScheduler.Default);

        public static TResult RunSync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> task) =>
            taskFactory
                .StartNew(task)
                .Unwrap()
                .GetAwaiter()
                .GetResult();
    }
}

As expected as the Task in the 'myForcedTimeoutMethod' function is not awaited the exception "Forced timeout reached" is never caught by the main thread.
I tried using Task.Run().ContinueWith(...) as well, but the continuation is also executed in a different scope.
The nearest solution I was able to achieve was to use a Thread.Interrupt() like this:
public static  ForcedTimeoutContext myForcedTimeoutMethod(int TimeInMs)
{

    ForcedTimeoutContext forcedTimeout = new ForcedTimeoutContext();
    forcedTimeout.TokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var currThread = Thread.CurrentThread;

    forcedTimeout.Task = Task.Run(async delegate
    {

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(TimeInMs), forcedTimeout.TokenSource.Token);
        currThread.Interrupt();
    });

    return forcedTimeout;
}

However, in this case I don't have any control over the exception and I wish to be able to throw a specific exception.
Is there any way to throw an exception in the main Thread from an async Task without awaiting for it?
EDIT: The reason I can't change how the main thread calls the method is because I'm using a low code platform that generates the code. I don't have control over the main thread, I can only "inject" functions that will be called by the main thread, which will also run other low code elements that I don't have control over. I also can't define a timeout at server level for the method.
Using the code above to give a practical example, what I can do is create the code of a function like 'myForcedTimeoutMethod' and say to the code generator that I want that to be executed in the main thread, but I can't control how it will be called. So I can't use an extension method for example to wrap multiple tasks.
I'm not expecting the logic to 'magically stop' or the code to do magic. I'm aware this is an unusual problem and might not smell good, but that's the scenario I have. I'm asking for help to find an unusual solution for an unusual problem.
The problem I'm trying to address is to have a timeout I can control on server side.
EDIT 2: Although I'm using a console application in the example, the actual code is running on an IIS application server as a result of a REST API call.
A reactive application calls the REST method that runs C# code.
The motivation behind this "forced timeout" is to ensure that the reactive application (client side) and the REST API (server side) have the same timeout.
I can control the timeout on the client side, but I can't control the timeout on the server side (which is 110 seconds by default in IIS)
Having different timeouts on the client and server can cause the request to time out on the client but continue running on the server, meaning the client side never knows if the request has completed.

Please fix indentation. This code is really annoying to read.

So, are you expecting logic magically stops all the execution sort of Hey, forced timeout is here!? - it doesn't work this way. You have to wait, that's the idea of timeout - to fall into timespan or not. What exact problem are you trying to address?

Did you try using a CTOR Overload for CTS that takes a timeout ? Ex: "Initializes a new instance of the CancellationTokenSource class that will be canceled after the specified delay in milliseconds." ...

just for context: ThreadInterruptedException is thrown in the interrupted thread, but not until the thread blocks. If the thread never blocks, the exception is never thrown, and thus the thread might complete without ever being interrupted. link docs. Maybe Thread.Abort if you are on .NET Framework

^^ No. NEVER Thread.Abort.

If the API does not support cancellation, then best-effort is probably to await the timeout or that call and depending on which completes first, ignore the result or use it. Which doesn't cancel the operation, but allows your flow to progress after at most timeout time.

This is almost certainly an XY Problem. Tasks aren't threads. There's no thread involved in eg Task.Delay, it's a timer that triggers a TaskCompletionSource after a while. There's no thread involved when awaiting the response from a remote service and even then, aborting that thread wouldn't abor the remote work. Finally, CPU bound tasks are executed by pooled threads. If you call Thread.Abort you won't just stop the task, you'll kill a thread that would be used for other work. Which is why Thread.Abort is a terrible idea

I can't change how the methods are called in the main thread why? What do those methods actually do and why can't they change? Are these external libraries? Your own code managed by another team? Or are you assuming you can't change that code? External libraries may have their own way of cancellation. Or you may be able to break the work in batches that are easier to abandon. If the call is a remote one, you'll have to call that service's cancellation API, or stop waiting and let the remote work go to waste.

"Is there any way to throw an exception in the main Thread from an async Task without awaiting for it?" -- Are you sure that you are asking the right question? From a quick inspection of your code, it seems to me that you want the exception to be thrown inside the Main method, not just in the main thread, and you want to handle the exception with the try/catch block inside the Main method. Is my understanding correct?

@Fildor I improved the indentation, thanks for the heads up.
I also added extra info for more context, I tried to use the CancellationToken with a timeout, but the problem is that I still can't wait for the task so any exception thrown inside the task will not be caught.  I can't wait for it because I want the rest of the code to keep  running, and unfortunately I can't run the rest of the code as a task as well.
And I don't want to use Thread.Interrupt or Abort, that's why I'm looking for an alternative.

@Ryan I added more context on why I can't wait for the task. I know it doesn't work this way, that's why I'm asking for help to find an alternative solution.

@PanagiotisKanavos I also added context to the question on why I can't change the main method. I'm using a code generator that I don't have control over. I can only inject functions to be called by the main thread.

@TheodorZoulias this is an exemple, but you could say that is true. I want to be able to catch the exception on the method that is calling the others.

@user2962069 I'm using a low code, code generator tool. First, which tool, specifically? I find it hard to believe it doesn't support async and cancellation in 2024. Second, those are two different things. Code generators aren't "low code" and do allow you to adapt the code. As for "low-code" you just discovered what every other developer in the last 30 years already discovered - they aren't really, and require more work to do what you want

@user2962069 what is the actual problem you want to solve? You don't need any code generator to write a Main function. Perhaps you have a workflow tool and want to call a remote API or database? A GUI builder that needs to make a remote call now? Tried using an anti-automation RPA tool instead of an ETL tool to process data? Workflow and ETL tools/libraries always include timeout/cancellation functionality

@PanagiotisKanavos, I'm using a low code platform.
This platform is not bad at all, and it really helps. The platform name is OutSystems.
It is a full stack and full lifecycle platform, and as part of it's process it generates all the code you need and hot deploy it to the cloud.
The server side code is generated as C#, and is deployed to an IIS application server which is hosted in AWS as a SaaS.
Due to that I don't have access to the server and to the code generated by the platform itself.

@PanagiotisKanavos However, for more advanced scenarios this platform also allows you to write your own C# functions in high code, that are then used in the low code platform as 'Actions'.
These actions are simple C# functions that are executed in a main thread.
The issue I want to solve is to timeout this request using C# code given the limitations I mentioned.
The reason is because as part of this low code platform on the Client Side we have a different timeout than the server side. And in case the request times out in the Client Side, there is a chance for it to continue on Server.

This scenario is what I'm trying to avoid.
Does it make sense to you?

@user2962069 more than you expect - I was the chief architect of a model driven platform back in the 2000s (yes, and workflows, and generated UI and entities and reports and data warehouses), and worked in a similar area again in 2010-ish. The names change (4GL, RAD, MDA, ant latelylow-code) but the fundamental problem is that both business and technology changes faster than such systems can adapt. And the system you tried to use now can't handle background processing. Although, to be fair, the RAD tool isn't built to handle background jobs

So the real answer here is DON'T USE THE GUI ACTIONS to run the background job. You can use it to trigger the job by eg sending a message to the ETL tool (eg SSIS, Airflow, whatever). If Outsystems has the concept of a process or workflow (which almost all do), you're actually starting a long process. On AWS you can send notifications to SNS or SQS, or trigger AWS Lambda code

PS: You still haven't said what you try to do, only how you thought it would work. Searching the OutSystems web site I see there's a Background Processes module and courses on Async processes and Asynchronous data processing

@PanagiotisKanavos I'm not trying to run a background process. As you correctly mentioned, there are different ways to do that in the OutSystems platform. You can use either BPM or Timers, for instance. The problem I'm trying to solve is not related to an async background process, it is actually related to the timeout of a HTTP request.
Imagine a reactive app that calls a REST API in an IIS server that runs a C# code.
In the reactive app (Client Side) we have a timeout of 20 seconds. Meaning that after 20 seconds the Client will stop waiting for a response.

However, on the server side, the request will not necessarily timeout as we have a timeout of 110 seconds (default for IIS). Meaning that if the request takes more than 20 seconds for any reason, the Client Side will not be aware of that.
What I'm trying to do, is to ensure this that both sides have the same timeout value.
But given all the limitations mentioned above, I have very little options.
For example, I can't change the server timeout. Or change how the C# code is called on the server.

20 seconds is a long running job as far as any web application is concerned. In this question from the OutSystems forums the guideline is 5 seconds. In all SPAs you'd trigger the job with a request and either poll or use websockets to retrieve progress, not wait for 2 minutes for a response

@PanagiotisKanavo 20 seconds is just an example. You can consider a 5 seonds timeout on Client Side. However, in case the server request takes 6 seconds (Let's say because the system is under heavy load or any other reason). You already have a problem! The Client Side will timeout in 5 seconds, but the request on server side will be completed and will not timeout and the Client Side will never know it.

You can't casually cause an exception in a different thread. This reality is (at least in part) why CancellationToken exists for async code, which a cooperative form of cross-flow interrupt - but it demands that the code you want to be able to interrupt takes extra steps to allow itself to be interrupted (either via pre-check, or delegate callback).
There is no magic you want weave here.

Marc, I added more context on my scenario.
I know it is unusual, but I'm in a very limited scenario.
I can't control how the methods are called in the main thread to allow it to be interrupted as well.

@user2962069 you haven't explained the actual problem yet. The obvious thing is that the wrong tool was used for the job. What's the actual job?

@Panagiotis if you want to allure the OP into providing clarifications, you could use the comments under the question to ask for clarifications, instead of using them to share your knowledge. We know that your are knowledgeable, and I am saying it honestly, not ironically. You don't have to prove it again and again in the comments of every single question. By not following the rules of the site, you don't help at improving the quality of the questions in this site.

Under the assumptions that:

The methods that you call in the main thread cannot do cooperative cancellation via cancellationToken
Those methods can still be executed on a worker thread
and you don't mind letting them finish/discarding those results
You really care about continuing execution on the main thread in timely manner

you can use an extension method on Task<TResult> similar to this (almost sure I stole this but don't remember the source) if you are on a version before .NET 6
public async static Task<TResult> WithTimeout<TResult>(
this Task<TResult> task, TimeSpan timeout) {
    Task firstToFinish = await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout))
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (firstToFinish != task) throw new TimeoutException();
    return await task.ConfigureAwait(false); // Unwrap result/re-throw
}

With .NET 6 and later, as Theodor Zoulias suggested in the comments, you could make use of the built-in Task.WaitAsync method. It provides further overloads accepting cancellationTokens too and is presumably more efficient and faster.
and an example use:
try {
    var result = await Task.Run(() => {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return 3;
    })
    // .WithTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500)); // test with < and > 2000
    .WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500)); //.NET 6+
    Console.WriteLine(result);

} catch (TimeoutException ex) {
    
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}


Starting from .NET 6, there is already a ​WaitAsync API that does exactly the same thing with your WithTimeout extension method, only more efficiently.

@TheodorZoulias thanks for the suggestion, edited to include it as default option for .NET6+.

Ivan, thanks for the answer!
The problem with the extension methods is that I can't call the functions as a Task to be able wait for their completion. I added more context to the question explaining why,
